# how to open a file in iWork in the iPad

Tags: iphone

From what I understand, `UIApplication -openFile` can open files externally, the application depending on the URL scheme.  Say I have a pages (or word maybe?) document, and I want to open it in pages from my app.  Does anyone know the URL scheme for me to do that?  Is there a list anywhere? (Keynote, and Numbers would also be useful).

Comment: I don't think that will work: Apple probably doesn't store the data as files: in the iPhone SDK they suggest against using the filesystem to store data--instead they suggest sqlite or some other form of database to minimize reads and writes to the flash memory. So, even if they had a URL protocol set up, you would need to find a way to reference the documents, because in all likelihood, it's not done via file paths.

Comment: What about a pages file downloaded from the web, say?

Comment: Also, I thought documents actually do exist somewhere in the app's folder, like pages or photos for example?

Comment: Maz: That's incorrect. All data on iOS is stored in a standard HFS filesystem.  Each application gets its own sandboxed area of the filesystem that other applications can't access.  Apple discourages displaying this sandboxed area as a folder/file structure and prefers domain-specific navigation models, but it's really just a filesystem underneath.

Comment: Okay, I remember seeing somewhere in the docs something about creating URLs that make reference to local files or something, this is mostly unrelated, and maybe I've been staring at them for too long or something.  Can anyone read minds?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way because you cannot transmit the file via a URL and Pages cannot access a file that is stored in your app's sandbox.

If you want to give the user the option to open a file in Pages in your UI, [UIDocumentInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the way to do that. It presents a UI where the user can preview the file and select to open it in any application that supports the file type.

AFAIK it is not possible with the SDK to do this completely programmatically, i.e. without user interaction.

Comment: Gah, I thought I saw somewhere in the docs about making URLs that refer to files in your app or something, but I don't remember, and now its bugging me.  Anyways, that's not really too relevant, but here, http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-other-apps-within-an-iphone-application.html, it looks like I can open files in Safari or Mail, and it looks like you can open files with third party apps if they support it, so I figured there might be a way to do it with iWork?

Comment: Even UIDocumentController uses URLs in the launch options key of the receiving app